# a quick time+poly saving trick (Remove a section of Edge Loop)

Tags: workflow

while trying to make a model low-poly I was wondering if there was a way that I could delete an edge and have blender automatically re-join the vertices! To get from the left state to the right state without taking any steps in-between

[image]

Comment: hit "X" and choose "Disolve edges"

Comment: @samd001, be more specific in the title of your question, to help others who want to do something similar, find your Question using the search feature.

Comment: @ Chebhou @zeffii

Comment: @samd001 is the problem solved

Comment: @Chebhou You should add that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

To remove this edges and keep the faces , do the selection and hit <kbd>X</kbd> then choose ***Dissolve Edges***  :

[image]